# create array of record counts with query

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, database, filter

```
DB::table('visitors')
        ->join('event_visitor', 'visitors.id', '=', 'event_visitor.visitor_id')->where('sex', 0)
        ->where('event_visitor.event_id', 1)
        ->count();
```

this is the query to get the count of men at the visitor's table with an event id of 1

I want to get the record count of men women and kids in 10 events and formate it like this

```
$men = [100, 200, 300 ,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000];
$women = [100, 200, 300 ,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000];
$kids = [100, 200, 300 ,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000];
```

is there a way to do this in the database without getting into the n+1 problem?

```
0 = men
1 = women
2 = kids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about laravel, but in MySQL you could write a query like

```
SELECT visitors.sex, event_visitor.event_id, count(*) as num_visits
  FROM visitors INNER JOIN event_visitor ON visitors.id = event_visitor.visitors_id
 WHERE event_visitor.event_id IN (1, 10, 15, 21, 25, 28, 30, 48, 59, 61)
 GROUP BY visitors.sex, event_visitor.event_id;
```

The numbers given after the `IN` keyword are ten sample event ids, for which you want to get a result. Note, that this counts visits not visitors. If you want to count distinct visitors, you can `count(DISTINCT visitors.id)`.

Comment: hi, is there a way to make this faster, my visitors table size now is 600k and the query takes 2s to load

Comment: @Abdoullahal-hajj you should ask a new question and include things like your table structure, indices and the output of the EXPLAIN statement.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is going to be like this in laravel

```
DB::table('visitors')
        ->select('visitors.sex', 'event_visitor.event_id', DB::raw('count(*) as num_visits'))
        ->join('event_visitor','visitors.id','=','event_visitor.visitor_id')
        ->whereIn('event_visitor.event_id',[1,2,3,4,5])
        ->groupBy('visitors.sex','event_visitor.event_id')
        ->get();
```